# How do I add a dependency to Grails?

Tags: java, grails, dependencies

I'm using grails with Netbeans and I'm simply trying to add a dependency.

Neither the commandline:

```
grails install-dependency org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.3m
```

Nor the BuildConfig.grooy:

```
dependencies {      
  runtime 'org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.3m'        
}
```

methods seemed to work for me. At least that, or Netbeans isn't realizing that the dependencies hava actually appeared. The project is not building and Netbeans claims that the packages / classes to not exist in the code editor.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the scope from "runtime" to compile to see if they show up?

And if you have set pom=true in your BuildConfig.groovy, you can add the dependency in your pom.xml and try that too

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mindrot</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbcrypt</artifactId>
    <version>0.3m</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: By the way, if you are using Grails 2.x version, you should have ":" in front of the dependency.    Ex: runtime ':org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.3m'

Comment: I decided not to use the plugin in the end, but as soon as I do, I'll test out your suggestion and mark this answer correct if ti works. Thanks for your effort.